# UITableView - Cells not colored on initial load?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am implementing `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in my VC.

I have this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    // do stuff 
    if(condition){
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Pretty standard stuff. The issue I am running into is that the first set of visible cells has no coloring. If I scroll to cells that aren't visible, I get correctly colored cells. If I scroll back, I the cells are colored.

I understand that the cells are 'created' and 'destroyed' as needed, which explains some of it, I just doesn't understand why `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which is fired before I see anything, **and** my coloring conditionals being hit, results in... no coloring.

A work around is to iterate through the visible cells after calling `reloadData` on the table view, I am just hoping there is an easier way.

Dane

Comment: Where did you put that condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cell coloring needs to be done in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, not the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Remove any cell coloring logic from the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and move it to the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.